# A question about android install apk and .so

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have collected an APP error：
`#01 pc 0000000000d59f50 /data/app/com.app.tv_app-2/lib/arm64/libxwalkcore.so [arm64-v8a::0baa318f30182034bd9d861bae2adba4]`

I can't understand the information in the error，such as "#01","pc","0000000000d59f50".

Can anyone help me interpret this exception and give me some suggestions？

**more information:**
This is my company’s APP, it only runs on our own device, so there is only one software environment and hardware environment. But a small number of devices have found this error, And I found re-install the apk can solve this problem. Is this a bug in the system installation? How to troubleshoot this problem？

Comment: Use [the ndk-stack tool](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-stack) to symbolize the stack trace from the crash.